# Why I get the Activity pause timeout exception when my data is large?

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, android-activity, timeout

I am using a collection of my object in my activity. I pass this collection from Activity ActDocumentDetails to ActProductsGallery. When my collection is not so large, I have no problem but when the size of collection is large enough I get this execption:

**Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40af3ef8 org.mabna.order/.ui.ActProductsGallery}**

How can I resolve this timeout problem?

Thanks in advance,

```
11-23 09:44:21.930: I/ActivityManager(134): No longer want com.asus.weather (pid 664): hidden #16
11-23 09:44:59.990: I/ActivityManager(134): No longer want com.android.email (pid 1259): hidden #16
11-23 09:44:59.990: I/ActivityManager(134): No longer want com.asus.DLNA (pid 1251): hidden #17
11-23 09:45:00.010: W/ActivityManager(134): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.DLNA/com.asus.DMS.DLNAServerService in 5000ms
11-23 09:45:00.010: W/ActivityManager(134): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.DLNA/.MusicPlaybackService in 15000ms
11-23 09:45:00.020: W/ActivityManager(134): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.asus.emailwidget/.UpdateService in 24997ms
11-23 09:45:05.020: I/ActivityManager(134): Start proc com.asus.DLNA for service com.asus.DLNA/com.asus.DMS.DLNAServerService: pid=1521 uid=10055 gids={3003, 1015}
11-23 09:45:05.060: I/DMS(1521):   ===========================>   onCreate()
11-23 09:45:10.210: W/ActivityManager(134): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40af3ef8 org.mabna.order/.ui.ActProductsGallery}
11-23 09:45:10.230: W/dalvikvm(1474): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4028c760)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:2686)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-23 09:45:10.230: E/AndroidRuntime(1474):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 09:45:10.240: W/ActivityManager(134):   Force finishing activity org.mabna.order/.ui.ActProductsGallery
11-23 09:45:10.270: W/ActivityManager(134):   Force finishing activity org.mabna.order/.ui.ActDocumentDetails
11-23 09:45:10.280: W/ActivityManager(134): Scheduling restart of crashed service org.mabna.order/.services.SrvSmsListener in 24735ms
11-23 09:45:10.280: E/InputDispatcher(134): channel '40f237e8 org.mabna.order/org.mabna.order.ui.ActDocumentDetails (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-23 09:45:10.280: E/InputDispatcher(134): channel '40f237e8 org.mabna.order/org.mabna.order.ui.ActDocumentDetails (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-23 09:45:10.280: W/ActivityManager(134): Scheduling restart of crashed service org.mabna.order/.services.SrvDataExchange in 34735ms
```

Comment: How do you pass those objects between your activities?

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(ActDocumentDetails.this,
     ActProductsGallery.class);
   intent.putExtra(
     "org.mabna.order.ui.entSaleDocumentDetailsCollection",
     boDocumentDetails.entSaleDocumentDetailsCollection);
   intent.putExtra("org.mabna.order.ui.selectedItem",
     boDocumentDetails.selectedItem);
   startActivityForResult(intent, DIALOG_PRODUCTS_GALLERY);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you're putting too much into your Intent. Consider having a static field, for example, within your Application object for passing large amounts of data between activities. Or even better a `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: could you please explain more about WeakHashMap

Comment: You put your data into a WeakhashMap under a certain key. You have that WeakHashMap as a field in your Application object. Then you read your data from your other activity using that key. Since you're using WeakHashMap garbage collector will take care of removing your entry if noone uses the key anymore. That is unlike a static variable or an ordinary hashMap where entries (of possibly big sizes) will remain until explicitly removed. Best is to see javadoc on WeakHashMap  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a good idea for using static variable and it resolved my problem.

Comment: Alex also see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053090/flash-toggle-button-crash-android

Comment: If you have an Object Model, repository, or other Model interface, consider only passing a UUID, ID, or other identifier of whatever you're trying to pass, along with limited details like document title.  Then, your new activity asynchronously grabs it's own copy and populates itself.  This way, you maintain a single source of truth, and reduce the amount of information you are passing between activities at the same time.