# Flash toggle button crash android

Tags: java, android, camera

> App is working fine in four different devices. but client is facing crash on flash buttton ON/OFF on **Xperia z2**.

**MainActivity**

```
btnFlash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Flash is toggled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(CameraPreview.isFlashOn)
                {
                    CameraPreview.FlashOff(camera);

                    CameraPreview.isFlashOn = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    CameraPreview.isFlashOn = true;

                    CameraPreview.FlashOn(camera);
                }
            }
        });
```

**CameraPreview**

```
  public static boolean isFlashOn =false; // 

  public static void FlashOn(Camera mCamera)
  {
        // Get Camera Params for customisation
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        // Check Whether device supports AutoFlash, If you YES then set
        // AutoFlash
        List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();

        if (flashModes.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
        {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        }
        else if (flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
        {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    public static void FlashOff(Camera mCamera)
    {
        // Get Camera Params for customisation
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        // Check Whether device supports AutoFlash, If you YES then set
        // AutoFlash
        List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (flashModes.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
        {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
```

**Crash Report.**

```
me_idx 0, stream type 9
W/ActivityManager(  973): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{45328828 u0
aus.xray.cam/.MainActivity2 t153 f}
D/mm-camera-intf( 9138): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: VIDIOC_DQBUF buf_index 6, fra
me_idx 840, stream type 1
I/mm-camera(  473): mct_pipeline_process_set:command=8000013
I/mm-camera(  473): pproc_module_handle_reprocess_offline:1318 input buf fd 126
type 4 size 462848
D/mm-camera-intf( 9138): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: VIDIOC_DQBUF buf_index 0, fra
me_idx 0, stream type 9
D/CustomizationProcess( 3778): dismissCustomizationDialog:true
I/WindowManager(  973): Screen frozen for +307ms due to Window{44e24b48 u0 Statu
sBar}
D/mm-camera-intf( 9138): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: VIDIOC_DQBUF buf_index 0, fra
me_idx 841, stream type 1
I/mm-camera(  473): mct_pipeline_process_set:command=8000013
I/mm-camera(  473): pproc_module_handle_reprocess_offline:1318 input buf fd 120
type 4 size 462848
D/mm-camera-intf( 9138): mm_stream_read_msm_frame: VIDIOC_DQBUF buf_index 1, fra
me_idx 0, stream type 9
^C
C:\adb>
```

Comment: have u got the solution,i am facing same issues

Comment: Yes I found the solution.

Comment: i have answered it for you . Muku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the request of muku. I answered it my self. for toggling flash

```
flashBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public onClick(View view)
    {
        if(cameraView!=null)//cameraView is the CameraPreview.class
        {
            if(cameraView.isFlashOn() && isFlashRunning)
            {       
                cameraView.FlashOff(camera);

                isFlashRunning = false;                             
            }
            else
            {
                cameraView.FlashOn(camera); 

                isFlashRunning = true;  
            }
    }
});
```

**And FlashOn and FlashOff methods are**

```
public void FlashOn(Camera mCamera) throws RemoteException
    {   
        // Get Camera Params for customisation
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        // Check Whether device supports AutoFlash, If you YES then set
        // AutoFlash
        List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();

        if (flashModes.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
        {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

            isFlashOn = true;
        }
        else if (flashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))
        {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);

            isFlashOn = true;
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.startPreview();

        //mCamera.autoFocus(null);  // may be this is problem
    }



    public void FlashOff(Camera mCamera) throws RemoteException
    {
        // Get Camera Params for customisation
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        // Check Whether device supports AutoFlash, If you YES then set
        // AutoFlash
        List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();

        if (flashModes.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
        {
            parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

            isFlashOn = false;
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
```